# Another null collection being passed to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need additional eyes to see:

1. What I am doing wrong as I try to pass a collection of objects to a MVC controller and all I get is sgList = null.
2. How can I check so that I only save the rows that being changed.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(IList<EZone_ServiceGroup> sgList)
   {
       try
       {
           foreach (EZone_ServiceGroup sg in sgList)
               svcGroupRepo.UpdateServiceGroup(sg);

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       catch
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<KTCEzone.Domain.Entities.EZone_ServiceGroup>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-striped small" id="sgTable">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-sm-12">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GroupID)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GroupName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ParentGroupID)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderIndex)</th>
            </tr>

            @{var items = Model.ToArray();}
            @for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items[i].GroupID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => items[i].GroupName) </td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => items[i].ParentGroupID) </td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => items[i].Active) </td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => items[i].OrderIndex) </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Model:

```
public class EZone_ServiceGroup
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int OrderIndex { get; set; }
    public int ParentGroupID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model to `@model IList<KTCEzone.Domain.Entities.EZone_ServiceGroup>`, and remove `@{var items = Model.ToArray();}` from the view and use

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].GroupID)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m=> m[i].GroupName)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m=> m[i].ParentGroupID)</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m[i].Active) </td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m=> m[i].OrderIndex) </td>
  </tr>
}
```

which will correctly name your elements. If you cannot change the collection to IList, then you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type of the model, and use in conjunction with `@Html.EditorFor()`

As for *"How can I check so that I only save the rows that being changed"*, all controls will be posted back, so you need to compare the posted values with the original values in the controller.

Comment: @Steplen: That works. Would you mind explain why IList will produce different output comparing to IEnumerable? I see the HTML generate from your code as name="[1].GroupID" while my code will generate name="items[1].GroupID"

Comment: @TL, Your own comment actually explains it :) Your implementation is giving the controls a name with the "item" prefix. In order for this to bind to a model, your model would need to contain a property named `items` which is a collection (denoted by `[#]`) of complex objects, where the object would need to contain a property (denoted by the `.`) named `GroupID` (denoted by `GroupID`)

Comment: One way to think about this (and therefore how the `name` attribute must be generated) is to think about how you would access the property in c#. For example, `var model = new List<MyObject>() { // add some items };`. Then to access the value of a property in the first object of the collection, you would use `var groupID = model[0].GroupID;` Now just strip the "model" from it, and that's how the `name` attribute must be in the html.